# Calling functions with arguments from CoreFoundation using ctypes

Tags: python, macos, ctypes, coremidi

I am trying to access the CoreMidi functions from the CoreFoundation framework in MacOSX using ctypes in Python.

When I call a function that doesn't have any parameters, everything goes fine. For example, the following code:

```
from ctypes import *
core_midi = cdll.LoadLibrary("/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMIDI.framework/Versions/A/CoreMIDI")
numOfDevices = core_midi.MIDIGetNumberOfDevices()
print numOfDevices
```

returns

```
3
```

which is the number of MIDI devices in my computer.

However, I am not able to execute functions which require parameters. Check this example (**EDIT**: as eryksun pointed out, I was using a char* as client_name, and the function prototype demanded a CFString. I corrected this in the code example below but I still get the same error):

```
core_midi = cdll.LoadLibrary("/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMIDI.framework/Versions/A/CoreMIDI")
client_name = core_foundation.CFStringCreateWithCString(None, "MIDI Client", 0) 
midi_client = c_uint()
result = core_midi.MIDIClientCreate(client_name, None, None, byref(midi_client))
print midi_client
print result
```

This code doesn't print anything at all, doesn't even raise an exception. The MIDIClientCreate function's prototype is:

```
extern OSStatus MIDIClientCreate(
    CFStringRef name, 
    MIDINotifyProc notifyProc, 
    void *notifyRefCon, 
    MIDIClientRef *outClient );
```

MIDIClientRef is defined as a UInt32, and, as I understand, it receives a pointer to a MIDIClient structure that is created, that is why I use byref() to pass it as a parameter. If I just pass the variable without byref(), the function call returns a value -50, which probably indicates some bizarre error.

**EDIT**: I am not sure if I am creating the CFString correctly. I tried to test the result with the following code but it doesn't print anything on screen.

```
client_name = core_foundation.CFStringCreateWithCString(None, "MIDI Client", 0)
cstr = ctypes.create_string_buffer(20)
core_foundation.CFStringGetCString(client_name, cstr, 20, 0)
print cstr
```

Thanks!

**EDIT**: Answered by eryksun!

I didn't know this of course, but setting the pointers is not as obvious as my naive example was trying to do.

```
class _CFString(Structure):
    pass

cf_path = ctypes.util.find_library("CoreFoundation")
cm_path = ctypes.util.find_library("CoreMIDI")

core_foundation = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(cf_path)
core_midi = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(cm_path)

CFStringRef = POINTER(_CFString)

midi_client = ctypes.c_uint()
core_foundation.CFStringCreateWithCString.restype = CFStringRef
core_foundation.CFStringCreateWithCString.argtypes = [c_void_p, c_char_p, c_uint32]
client_name = core_foundation.CFStringCreateWithCString(None, "MIDI Client", 0)

core_midi.MIDIClientCreate.argtypes = [CFStringRef, c_void_p, c_void_p, POINTER(c_uint32)]    
result = core_midi.MIDIClientCreate(client_name, None, None, byref(midi_client))

print midi_client
print result
```

Actually, I though restype and argtypes didn't affect how functions were executed or how parameters were passed to them, but it seems that they do.

The above code results in:

```
c_uint(4657178L)
0
```

That is, my MIDI client is created somewhere and the function returns without error.
Thanks again eryksun!

Comment: Oh, well spotted eryksun. I tried to create a CFString using CFStringCreateWithBytes but I still haven't succeeded. I edited the question in order to reflect this. I think I am messing up with the byref parameters...

Comment: Hey eryksun, that was it, thanks so much! Write an answer so I can mark you as the answerer.

Comment: BTW, just setting the restyle was enough... I think you were right about the 64bit result pointer being truncated...